# postmark app with devise - registration and forgot password emails

Tags: postmark

I cannot get postmark to handle registration and forgot password emails:

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  default from: "donotreply@barnpix.com"

  def confirmation_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions)
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions)
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions)
  end

  # you can then put any of your own methods here
end
```

application.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method   = :postmark
    config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_key => ENV['9302106a-63xxxx-xxx-xx-'] }
```

user.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

devise.rb

```
config.mailer = "UserMailer" # UserMailer is my mailer class
```

I cannot get this to work at all. Any hints as to what I might be doing wrong or what I might be missing to get this to work ?

Comment: Probably not a problem for you anymore, but the [docs](https://postmarkapp.com/loves/rails) point to using `api_token`, not `api_key`.  (They also suggest hard-coding the token though, which is probably not a great idea.)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is caused by this line:

```
config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_key => ENV['9302106a-63xxxx-xxx-xx-'] }
```

`ENV` is a hash of all environment variables. You should use names to access the values. I guess you’re using Postmark on Heroku, so it will be `ENV['POSTMARK_API_KEY']` in that case.

Comment: ok thanks! so where will I put my Postmark API key if I am not entering it here?

Comment: config.action_mailer.delivery_method   = :postmark
    config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_key => ENV['POSTMARK_API_KEY'] }

Comment: I am now getting this error: ArgumentError in Devise::PasswordsController#create

wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)